# How to use flask_mysqldb with blueprint

Tags: python, flask

I´m using flask_mysqldb with a blueprint and I want to initialize MySQL but I have an error:

> app.config.setdefault('MYSQL_HOST', 'localhost') AttributeError:
>   'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'config'

here i create the app

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from .bodega import bodega


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    cors = CORS(app, resources=r'/*')

    app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = "localhost"
    app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = "root"  # Usuario de la base de datos
    app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ""  # Contraseña de la base de datos
    app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = "inventario_bodega"  # Nombre de la base de datos
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisisthesecrectkey_de_uepc_2019'
    # app.config.from_object(Config)

    app.register_blueprint(bodega)

    return app
```

that´s my blueprint

```
from flask import Blueprint
bodega = Blueprint("bodega", __name__, url_prefix="/bodega")
from . import views
```

and here i want to use MySQL

```
from flask import jsonify
from datetime import datetime

from . import bodega
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

# the error is here
mysql = MySQL(bodega)


@bodega.route('/show', methods=['GET'])
def show_bodega():
    try:
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute(
            """SELECT * FROM bodega 
            join item on bodega.id_item = item.id_item 
            join usuarios on bodega.id_usuario = usuarios.id_usuario 
            join images on bodega.id_image = images.id_image"""
        )
        data = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        return jsonify(data), 202
    except:
        return "Error al extraer datos", 500
```

the application ask me to pass config to blueprint but i don´t how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This library looks pretty much dead to me. There's barely any any activity on the [github repo](https://github.com/admiralobvious/flask-mysqldb) and all of this would be covered by [flask-sqlalchemy](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy) anyway.

---

You don't want to initialise the db connection inside the blueprint. You want it in your application factory.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from .bodega import bodega

from flask_mysqldb import MySQL # Add the import in __init__

db = MySQL()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    cors = CORS(app, resources=r'/*')

    app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = "localhost"
    app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = "root"
    app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ""
    app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = "inventario_bodega"
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisisthesecrectkey_de_uepc_2019'

    db.init_app(app) # Initialise with the new app

    app.register_blueprint(bodega)

    return app
```

Then import the database (db) into your blueprint

```
from flask import jsonify
from datetime import datetime

from . import bodega
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

from app import db # Import from app here


@bodega.route('/show', methods=['GET'])
def show_bodega():
    try:
        cur = db.connection.cursor() # create a cursor
        cur.execute(
            """SELECT * FROM bodega 
            join item on bodega.id_item = item.id_item 
            join usuarios on bodega.id_usuario = usuarios.id_usuario 
            join images on bodega.id_image = images.id_image"""
        )
        data = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        return jsonify(data), 202
    except:
        return "Error al extraer datos", 500
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on the following line

```
mysql = MySQL(bodega)
```

instead, you should pass app to `MySQL`

```
app = create_app()
mysql = MySQL(app)
```

for more consider, reading docs: https://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: i tried to do that but i had an error ```from app import create_app
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app' from 'app' (C:\Users\Becario\Desktop\uepc-bodega-backend\app\_init_.py) ```

Comment: I think there is some other issue with the imort